# how to build altcoin in mingw?

Tags: development, altcoin, leveldb

OS : Windows 10

Installed Dependencies:

- -qt4.8.6
- gcc 6.3.0
- boost 1_55_0
- berkeleyDB 4.8.30NC
- openssl 1.0.2l

I tried compiling with the following commands:

```
qmake "USE_UPNP=1" coin-pt.pro
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
```

That resulted in this error:

```
./build\leveldb.o:leveldb.cpp:(.text+0x664): undefined reference to leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, leveldb::DB**)'
./build\leveldb.o:leveldb.cpp:(.text+0x72b): undefined reference toleveldb::DestroyDB(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, leveldb::Options const&)' ./build\leveldb.o:leveldb.cpp:(.text+0x826): undefined reference to leveldb::Status::ToString[abi:cxx11]() const'
./build\leveldb.o:leveldb.cpp:(.text+0x9b3): undefined reference toleveldb::Status::ToStringabi:cxx11 const' ./build\txdb.o:txdb.cpp:(.text+0x39b): undefined reference to leveldb::Status::ToString[abi:cxx11]() const'
./build\txdb.o:txdb.cpp:(.text+0xcc5): undefined reference toleveldb::Status::ToStringabi:cxx11 const' ./build\txdb.o:txdb.cpp:(.text+0xeb4): undefined reference to leveldb::Status::ToString[abi:cxx11]() const'
./build\txdb.o:txdb.cpp:(.text+0x1520): more undefined references toleveldb::Status::ToStringabi:cxx11 const' follow collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status Makefile.Release:287: recipe for target 'release\Coin-qt.exe' failed mingw32-make: *** [release\Coin-qt.exe] Error 1
```

How do I fix this problem?

---

It is the result after the qmake command. It is part of the Makefile.Release file

```
LIBS = -L"c:\Qt\4.8.6\lib" build\bitcoin-qt_res.o -lshlwapi -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -ldb_cxx -lws2_32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lgdi32 -lboost_system-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_filesystem-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_program_options-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_thread-mgw63-mt-1_55 -LC:/deps/miniupnpc -lminiupnpc -liphlpapi  C:/toscoin-src/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a C:/toscoin-src/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a -lshlwapi -LC:/deps/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib -Lc:/deps/db-5.3.28.NC/build_unix -Lc:/deps/openssl-1.0.2l -LC:/deps/qrencode-3.4.4/.libs -lssl -lcrypto -ldb_cxx -lws2_32 -lshlwapi -lmswsock -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lgdi32 -lboost_system-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_filesystem-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_program_options-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_thread-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_chrono-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lQtGui4 -lQtNetwork4 -lQtCore4 -lpthread C:/toscoin-src/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a C:/toscoin-src/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not compile LevelDB. In your altcoin's source code, you should see a folder for leveldb. `cd` into that directory and build leveldb. There should be instructions for that in the leveldb folder.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. but I did compile LevelDB because i have LevelDB source in altcoin`s source folder

Comment: Just because the source is there does not mean that it was compiled. The makefile that you built with does not necessarily include instructions to build that code. IIRC, many altcoins are like this in that the leveldb stuff must be built separately as it uses separate makefiles.

Comment: if so recompiling to LevelDB?

Comment: Your last comment does not make sense. You need to build leveldb and put the resulting files (should be `.a` files in the right place so that they can be linked when you build the rest of your altcoin source code.

Comment: How do I know that compilation was not successful?

Comment: I confirmed that there is an leveldb object file.

Comment: Then it is not in a place where the linker is able to find it. Can you update your question with a link to the source code that you are building?

Comment: It is the result after the qmake command.

It is part of the Makefile.Release file

Comment: LIBS        =        -L"c:\Qt\4.8.6\lib" build\bitcoin-qt_res.o -lshlwapi -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -ldb_cxx -lws2_32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lgdi32 -lboost_system-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_filesystem-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_program_options-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_thread-mgw63-mt-1_55

Comment: -LC:/deps/miniupnpc -lminiupnpc -liphlpapi  C:/toscoin-src/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a C:/toscoin-src/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a -lshlwapi -LC:/deps/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib -Lc:/deps/db-5.3.28.NC/build_unix -Lc:/deps/openssl-1.0.2l -LC:/deps/qrencode-3.4.4/.libs -lssl -lcrypto -ldb_cxx -lws2_32 -lshlwapi -lmswsock -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lgdi32 -lboost_system-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_filesystem-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_program_options-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lboost_thread-mgw63-mt-1_55

Comment: -lboost_chrono-mgw63-mt-1_55 -lQtGui4 -lQtNetwork4 -lQtCore4 -lpthread C:/toscoin-src/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a C:/toscoin-src/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a

Comment: Please post your above comments as an edit to your original post, it is too hard to read here.

Comment: Sorry, show content

Comment: Do you see the files `libleveldb.a` and `libmemenv.a` in `C:/toscoin-src/src/leveldb/`?

Comment: The file located in C:\toscoin-src\src\leveldb directory

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could tell me how.